# Parsing an unknown XML read from a third-party webservice

Tags: delphi, xml-parsing

I'm trying to analyze the values of an XML like this (obtained from a third party web service), inserting the values in a tStringlist to examine them later

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<libretti pagina="1" n_pagine="1" n_libretti="2">
    <libretto cod_catasto="202000000011" 
              cod_chiave="5e9f2bf12" completo="si" 
              data="2020-04-21" resp_cognome="Colombo" 
              resp_nome="Gianluca" ub_comune="VILLAFRANCA DI VERONA" 
              ub_provincia="VR" ub_indirizzo="Via dei pini" 
              ub_civico="1" ub_palazzo="" ub_scala="" ub_interno=""/>
    <libretto cod_catasto="202000000012" 
              cod_chiave="5e9f2bfsw" completo="si" 
              data="2020-04-22" resp_cognome="Palumso" 
              resp_nome="Federico" ub_comune="VILLAFRANCA DI VERONA" 
              ub_provincia="VR" ub_indirizzo="Via Prosetta" 
              ub_civico="2" ub_palazzo="" ub_scala="" ub_interno=""/>
</libretti>
```

What I really need is to get a simple list of all the vaules in it like the following.

For example:

```
libretto:
cod_catasto="202000000011"
cod_chiave="5e9f2bf12"
ompleto="si"
data="2020-04-21"
resp_cognome="Colombo"
resp_nome="Gianluca" 
ub_comune="VILLAFRANCA DI VERONA" 
ub_provincia="VR" 
ub_indirizzo="Via dei pini" 
ub_civico="1" 
ub_palazzo="" 
ub_scala="" 
ub_interno=""
```

and so on...

I'm stuck with the code below, which doesn't list all the values but stops at the first one, showing only the value "libretto="

```
procedure TForm5.ParseCercaXMLToMemo(TestXML:String);
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  i: Integer;
  LDocument: IXMLDocument;
  LNodeElement, LNode: IXMLNode;
  LAttrValue: string;

begin
  LDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  LDocument.LoadFromXML(TestXML); 

  { Find a specific node. }
  LNodeElement := LDocument.ChildNodes.FindNode('libretti');

  if (LNodeElement <> nil) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to LNodeElement.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      LNode := LNodeElement.ChildNodes.Get(I);
      memo1.lines.add(LNode.NodeName + '=' + LNode.Text);
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Sorry but "Doesn't work" isn't a useful problem description. How does your code not working manifest itself?

Comment: @MartynA you are right. I'm sorry. I've updated the comment

Comment: Tks.  What is the value of `LNodeElement.ChildNodes.Count` that you get?

Comment: You should just use `LDocument.DocumentElement` to get the root element. What do you have in `LNodeElement.Attributes['n_libretti']`?

Comment: @Olivier LNodeElement.Attributes['n_libretti'] returns 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Oliver I tried this code that finally works as expected.

```
procedure TForm5.ParseCercaXMLToMemo(TestXML:String);
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  i,y: Integer;
  LDocument: IXMLDocument;
  LNodeElement, LNode: IXMLNode;
  LAttrValue: string;

begin
  LDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  LDocument.LoadFromXML(TestXML); { File should exist. }

  { Find a specific node. }
  LNodeElement := LDocument.ChildNodes.FindNode('libretti');
  if (LNodeElement <> nil) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to LNodeElement.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      for y := 0 to LNodeElement.ChildNodes[i].AttributeNodes.count-1 do
        begin
          memo1.lines.add(LNodeElement.ChildNodes[i].AttributeNodes[y].LocalName+' = '+LNodeElement.ChildNodes[i].AttributeNodes[y].Text);
        end;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Well done.  Which Delphi version are you using, anwhich version of the MS XML import unit (if you're using the MS XML parser)?

Comment: @MartynA I'm using Delphi Xe 10.3.3. I'm getting the XML data (as string) from a server, using SOAP architecture.

Comment: FYI, Embarcadero dropped “XE“ from Delphi version name after Delphi XE 9!